# funcion del driver de postgresql con sqlalchemy

Tags: python, base-de-datos, postgresql

Hola a todos soy nuevo usando base de datos con python y se que para conectar postgresql con sqlalchemy se usa la siguiente sentencia:

```
engine = create_engine(dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database)
```

Entiendo todos los parametros que hay que pasar menos el `dialect+driver`, para que sirve este parametro? cual es su funcion?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: En la documentación de SQLAlchemy para [Dialect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/index.html) tienes la explicación. Básicamente el dialecto establece el tipo de sistema de base de datos que quieres usar y el driver es la DBAPI que quieres usar para comunicarte con ese sistema

Answer (score 1):

No necesita especificar el parámetro `driver` en 99% de los casos de uso

> postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/my_db

Pero, si es necesario:

> postgresql+psycopg2://user:pass@localhost:5432/my_db

Ver más: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#database-urls